# Inconsistencies in the rendering of lists

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, markdown-rendering

Can some of these inconsistencies be remedied?

http://meta.stackoverflow.com behaves differently (somewhat *less* reasonable I'd say).
I posted a [**twin question there**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276000/939860). Note the *differences*.

== demo start ==

#### Bulleted list

- Item 1

  - There should be no extra vertical spacing between this line and Item 1.
- Item 2

Reset with `</p>`:

- Item 1

  - Just like here: no extra vertical spacing between this line and Item 1.

Reset with `</p>`:

- Item 1

  - But not here?
  - Sub-item 2

#### Numbered list

1. Item 1

   11. There should be no extra vertical spacing between this line and Item 1.
2. Item 2

Reset with `</p>`:

1. Item 1
   1.1 While this is not accepted as sub-item

Reset with `</p>`:

1. Item 1
   1.1 With the help of two blanks appended to above line.
2. Item 2. There should be no spacing above this one (like on SO).

#### Mix

1. Item 1

   - Aligned top again?
2. Item 2. Same as above.

Comment: As commented over there: Since redesign of the site layout is underway, this would be a good opportunity to slip in a fix. Just ran into this again: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27144759/939860

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the point you're making, since you point out various CSS inconsistencies but then talk about HTML structure in your answer. However, the CSS differences between MSO and MSE seem to be fixed now after the great CSS re-org that we had; the two posts look identical to me now. Since that seems to be the main point here, I'll consider this status-completed; please create a new, a bit more detailed, question with any issues that you think weren't addressed. Thanks!

Comment: @balpha: More detailed? Seriously? This is very detailed. The difference between MSE and MSO seems fixed in this browser (Firefox 38.0.5 on Windows 7). Another issue is obviously not fixed: spacing between item and sub-item changes for no apparent reason if another item is added.

Answer (score 5):

This is a duplicate answer from what I posted on the twin question, reposted for me to prove to myself that they do remain consistent over relying on Markdown:

```
<ol> <!-- Numbered List -->
  <li>First numbered point.
    <ul> <!-- Sub-Bullet List -->
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li>World</li>
      <p><li>And The Internet</li></p>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Next numbered point.</li>
  <li>Very next numbered point.</li>
  <p><li>Distant point.</li>
  <li>Groups with the last point.
    <ul> <!-- Sub-Bullet List -->
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li>World</li>
      <p><li>And The Internet</li></p>
    </ul>
  </li></p>
  <li>A numbered point outside the group.</li>
</ol>
```

1. First numbered point.

   - Hello
   - World
     And The Internet
2. Next numbered point.
3. Very next numbered point.
  Distant point.

  Groups with the last point.

  - Hello
  - World
    And The Internet
4. A numbered point outside the group.

No they don't behave as nicely as on the other post :(

Comment: Then we need a formatting sandbox for MSO to check formatting differences.